# JQuery functions not launching in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm completely new to programming in ASP.NET and any form of web application developement. I've tried looking for answer but couldn't find any related problems. Most probably it's simple begginers mistake, but I've run out of ideas what might be the cause. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 if that's relevant.

In the master page in head I've included:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/custom.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In custom.js I've created function for testing purpouses, but it never triggers, like any other:

```
$(document).click(function () {
alert("Alert using jQuery");
});
```

What's most interesting js functions put in the custom.js file are working properly, but none of JQuery functions, even simplest one like above don't seem to be ever launched.

What confuses me most is that I've tried using online compilers and there it worked perfectly. Also Jquery 1.10.2 is included in project. Any ideas what might be the issue? Thanks for your time, lads!

Comment: Open your console, do you see any errors?

Comment: You say Jquery 1.10.2 is included in the project, but have you loaded the file in your master page ?

Comment: Have you tried using document ready function? `$(function(){$(document).click(function () {
alert("Alert using jQuery");
});});`

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined", should have noticed that. I will dig into that, thanks!

Comment: We need more data to help, show the entire head tag and script tags. But you probably are executing jQuery functions before jQuery is loaded

Comment: Load Jquery in your site master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not loaded the JQuery file. That's why you see `$ is not defined`. That's also why the functions on the `custom.js` file that are not using JQuery are working.

The same way you loaded the `custom.js` file, you need to load the 1.10.2 JQuery file.

Comment: That seems to be the problem. I was sure that it is loaded automagically, as it is generated with the project. Yet again thanks for your time!